# Pandas - Series of Dictionaries to Dataframe - Array size too big

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of dictionaries like so - lets call it `df`:

```
    0    {'a':0, 'b':2}
    1    {'c':0, 'd':2}
    2    {'a':0, 'd':2}
```

Target Dataframe:

```
    a    b    c    d
0   0    2    Nan  Nan
1   Nan  Nan  0    2
2   0    Nan  Nan  2
```

I would like this series to be put into a dataframe with the keys as headings and the data within the rows.
But it is roughly 1 million in length with up to 600+ parameters within each "row".

If I run `pd.DataFrame(df.tolist())` I receive the error
`ValueError: array is too big; 'arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize' is larger than the maximum possible size`

Are there any other methods available?

EDIT:
I have tried this -

```
b = pd.DataFrame()
split_size = 20000
for i in range(1, ceil(len(df2)/split_size)):
    index = i*split_size
    b = b.append(df2[:][index - split_size:index].tolist(), sort=False)
```

but still receive `MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (638, 40000) and data type float64`

Comment: why don't you cut the list?

Comment: What does your target result look like using the current example? This would help us figure out what you're trying to do :)

Comment: @JimEisenberg added target dataframe

Comment: @ansev I have tried splitting it up 50K and 40K at a time but I receive a memoryError. Going to try smaller now

Comment: Are you have many NaNs in your data? Then try to use sparse matrix for your task. Read this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html